# ELL answers out of sync with ELU answers

Tags: discussion, english-language-and-usage

An [ELL question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/65151/meaning-waiting-for-6-hours-vs-6-hours-since-i-was-waiting) got some highly upvoted answers that don't jive with the answers given at English Language & Usage on [a related question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/269282/difference-between-its-been-2-weeks-since-i-spoke-vs-since-i-was-speaking).

I am concerned that the ELL readers are being given unhelpful guidance on this matter.  What can be done about this?

Comment: Um, sorry, but I don't think that tag is going to be useful. It would have had some use if ELL would've been a very young SE.

Comment: In case anyone is curious but lazy, the tag that is apparently not useful was "contradiction-ell-elu".

Comment: The questions are quite different. I'm not sure why you think they disagree. Can you please explain?

Comment: @Catija - *The questions are quite different.*  I wonder, Do you mean perhaps that the threads are different?  Or that the answers are different?

Comment: I mean that the example sentences used are quite different and equating them to each other is not really necessarily appropriate.

Answer (score 8):

I don't see a conflict between the answers on ELU and those on ELL. I **do** notice that the answers on ELU don't agree with *each other*, nor do the answers on ELL.

This happens very frequently on both sites, particularly with questions respecting tense, aspect and modality. A few people give answers which are flat-out wrong; these generally get downvoted or at least ignored. Other people give answers which are *partially* correct. Sometimes they offer a sweeping rule which happens to work in the immediate context, overlooking contexts within which the rule doesn't work. Sometimes their answers assume a context which is not quite the same as that intended by the questioner. Sometimes they deny grammaticality to an expression which is deprecated by some 'authority', or assert grammaticality for an expression which is peculiar to a particular dialect or register. Sometimes they attempt a heroically comprehensive treatment which founders on the inadequacy of existing grammatical tools.

This is always going to be the case with questions addressing really fundamental grammatical categories—the sort of question that is likely to be raised on both sites rather than one or the other.

And this is always going to be the case in a short-form Q/A format like SE's, designed for one-off answers or readily memorized brief rules rather than analysis of the inexhaustible perversity of English as she is actually spoken and written.

Comment: I can understand why this OP posted an answer saying "It's been 6 hours since I was waiting for you" *would not be uttered by a native speaker of English* - but it's obviously not true (except in contexts where the intended meaning is "I have been waiting for you for 6 hours"). Excluding the two with currently *negative* vote totals, I can't offhand see anything conflicting between any other answers there. The ELU question is a bit of a shambles though (not exactly helped, imho, by this OP's contribution there).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - *The ELU question is a bit of a shambles though* -- Care to help unshamble it?

Comment: @aparente001: Not really. I think the ELU question should have been posted on ELL in the first place. There are subtle differences between *I have been waiting for X* and *I have been speaking with X* (as implied by deadrat's post, to do with the fact that you could have been *regularly* speaking with X, but you probably couldn't contrive a context where you regularly waited for him). But I doubt any native speaker could seriously take issue with the basic grammar of *It's been a month since I was sunning myself on the Riviera*, for example. Grammatically and semantically, that's fine.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The key thing, at least on this side of the Great Divide, is that we should explain very meticulously under what circumstances your *Riviera* sentence is acceptable and how it differs from the *waiting* sentence. That may not be necessary on the far side, where it may be presumed that readers recognize the difference without instruction.